# Safety deleting elements of the container

Tags: c++, containers, std

Could you suggest safety deleting of element of std::vector in to cases:
1. Clear all elements of the vector;
2. Erase one element depending on condition.

What are the dangers of this code:

```
    typename std::vector<T*>::iterator it;
    for (it=std::vector<T*>::begin();it!=std::vector<T*>::end();it++)
    {
        if (*it) delete *it;
    }
```

Thank's.

Comment: I could. But you haven't made it clear what you are actually stuck on.

Comment: Look up what `delete` does. The code is built on superstition and prejudice. Then learn the lesson. Programming is not an act of faith.

Comment: That is codes from my project. I found that element of this vector can be used after its deleting - and it produces crash of my system

Comment: Surely it might still crash if you try to dereference null. What are you trying to do? Take the pointers of of the vector so the vector has fewer elements afterwards, or leave them it so they blow up/other UB if you dereference them? You might be confusing deleting what a pointer in a vector points to, and erasing that element from a vector.

Comment: @doctorlove - there are situation where it makes sense to leave a `nullptr` in a vector instead of erasing the vector element. That doesn't lead to a blow up/UB by itself.

Comment: True - that's why I said "if you dereference them" which I said because of the OP's comment " I found that element of this vector can be used after its deleting - and it produces crash of my system " I suspect the same will happen with a nullptr.

Comment: @doctorlove - you could be right - you could be wrong! It depends...  If all uses of elements from the vector includes a check for `nullptr` there would be no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't remove the element from the vector. So the vector element is pointing to the location as before, i.e. the same T. However, since you have deleted that T you can not dereference the pointer anymore - that would be UB and may crash your program.

`delete` is calling the destructor of T (great, it's something you shall do) but `delete`is not changing the vector. Consequently the iterator is valid all the time.

Either you should remove the element for which you have called delete or at least set the vector element to nullptr.

```
typename std::vector<T*>::iterator it;
for (it=std::vector<T*>::begin();it!=std::vector<T*>::end();it++)
{
    delete *it;
    *it = nullptr;  // Only needed when you don't erase the vector element
}
```

**That solution requires that you always check for nullptr before using any element of the vector.**

In most cases the best solution is however to remove the element from the vector.

In the case where you destroy all elements by calling `delete` on every element, simply call `clear` on the vector after the loop.

Comment: Yes I agree - but what is about iterator? Does it valid after deleting? And what is about c++11? What are the other options?

Comment: Yes - the iterator is valid because you didn't erase any elements in the vector. Delete is calling the destructor of T but not changing the vector.

Answer (score 1):

For example, for you first two questions which appeared to regard clearing a vector

```
std::vector<int> v;//maybe have elements or not...
```

1. Clear the vector by calling `clear`

   ```
   v.clear();
   ```
2. If you wish to remove elements while you walk over the vector which satisfy a condition (i.e. a predicate) using `v.erase(it)` you need to be careful. Fortunately, `erase` returns the iterator after the removed position,  so something like

   ```
   for (auto it=v.begin();it!=v.end();)
   {
        if (predicate(it))
            it = v.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
   }
   ```

   Obviously you can use `std::remove_if` instead (with `std::erase`) if you want to shrink your vector slightly, avoiding a "awfully performant hand-written remove_if" as a commenter described this.

If you want to delete things as you loop round, you can either hand-do a loop yourself or use an algorithm - but smart pointers make far more sense. I suspect you *are* wanting to delete the items possibly in addition to shrinking the vector since you said " I found that element of this vector can be used after its deleting". If you do want to store raw pointers in a container, just `delete` the items, you don't the the `if` in your suggested code. You need to consider when you plan on doing this. 
Note: changing the contents of an iterator doesn't invalidate an iterator.

You should consider using smart pointers, for exception safety etc.

Comment: Downvote for awfully performant hand-written remove_if idiom.